# Android handler not repeating

Tags: android, handler

I'm trying to use "handler" to repeat a function (really trying to learn how to use it), but the function is only executed once.

```
public Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (changeColor) {
                myPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                Rect r = new Rect(0, 0, widthInPixels * 90, heightInPixels * 90);
                myCanvas.drawRect(r, myPaint);
                changeColor = false;
            } else {
                myPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                Rect r = new Rect(0, 0, widthInPixels * 90, heightInPixels * 90);
                myCanvas.drawRect(r, myPaint);
                changeColor = true;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 1000);
        }

    };


    public void play (View view) {
       handler.post(runnableCode);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `loop` through your `handler` to **repeat** itself. But you are just calling it **once**.

**Try** this code below:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
int count = 0; //keep track of count

final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() { 
        if (count++ < 5) { //how many times do you want to repeat?
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000); //repeat handler
        }
    } 
}; 

//initial trigger
handler.post(runnable);
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

Comment: Still no repetition. Also, does it have t be a finite loop? Can it not be until I decide to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your bool `changeColor` is being modified by making it a final one element array

Try code below:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final boolean[] changeColor = {false};
Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (changeColor[0]) {
            // code here
            changeColor[0] = false;
        } else {
            // other code here
            changeColor[0] = true;
        }
        messageHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }

};
handler.post(runnableCode);
```

Comment: No, it's still not changing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a "toast", and that does get repeated; the problem's the drawing for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I tried firing the function from a button, and it looks like the repetitions accumulate and then fire all at once when I hit the button again.

Answer (score 0):

Still fighting with this. I've also tried a timer, thread.sleep and ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, and nothing.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: It's no actually a solution; I cannot get this to work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.